# break statement is not working under a def function of for loop

Tags: python-3.x, break

Iam using break statement but it doesn't bring out of loop ,
I tried to find prime factors of given number but due to malfunctioning of break i cant do it

```
     def fact(x):
        for i in range(2,x+1):
            if x%i==0:
                xx.append(i)
                x=x//i
                if x==1:
                    break
                else:
                    print('fact')
                    fact(x)
    a=12
    xx=[]
    fact(a)
    print(xx)
```

Comment: Breaks fine for me and prints `[2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2]` although that doesnt look right but thats another issue

Comment: You have two "loops" in your code: the `for` loop, and the recursion. `break` is only going to break out of one of them.

Comment: If `x%i==0` you want to **both** call `fact(x)` with the new value of `x` and (then) `break`. Your second if is not needed.

Comment: You should use `return` if you want to end both the loop, and the function call

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is that you are "double counting" factors.

*having identified a factor, add it and call recursively with the number that results after removing the factor.*

At the moment, you do that, but then also look for the next factor in the current function call.

There are of course little ways to improve this some more like skipping over values of `i` that we know cannot be factors of `n` and making the function return the array of results itself rather than updating a global, but this will get you going:

With the lightest modification to your existing code what you want to do is:

```
def fact(x):
    for i in range(2,x+1):
        if x%i == 0:
            xx.append(i)
            fact(x//i)
            return

xx=[]
fact(12)
print(xx)
```

This will show you:

```
[2, 2, 3]
```